# Scrape website with load more button with R (rvest)

Tags: r, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to scrape a website with a load more button. I've set up a selenium server by using a windows prompt. The Selenium server is running, but I keep getting the following error when I run the script in R. I've red a lot of blog posts and tried to find the answer, but I lack the technical knowledge to figure this out, so I hope someone is willing to help me.

**Error**

> [1] "Connecting to remote server"
>
> Selenium message:The path to the driver executable must be set by the 
>   webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see 
>   https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be
>   downloaded  from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
>
> Error:     Summary: UnknownError       Detail: An unknown server-side error
>   occurred while processing the command.     class:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException    Further Details: run errorDetails
>   method

**Windows prompt**

```
cd c:\selenium
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=c:\geckodriver\chromedriver.exe -
Dwebdriver.gecko.driver.driver=c:\geckodriver\geckodriver.exe -jar selenium-
server-standalone-3.4.0.jar
```

**R SCRIPT**

```
library(rvest)
library(RSelenium)
library(stringr)
library(xm12)
library(wdman)
url <- "https://www.social-enterprise.nl/wie-doen-het/" 

remDr <- remoteDriver()
# Open the browser webpage
remDr$open()

#navigate to your page
remDr$navigate(url)

# Locate the load more button
loadmorebutton <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', "#morenews")

for (i in 1:2){
  print(i)
  loadmorebutton$clickElement()
  Sys.sleep(30)
}
page_source<-remDr$getPageSource()

Merken <- read_html(page_source[[1]]) %>% 
  html_nodes("#membershipCntr span") %>%
  html_text()
remDr$close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some options in remote web driver instantiate. You can try the following code,

```
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost" 
                      , port = 4444L
                      , browserName = "firefox"
                      )
```

Comment: I've tried the code, but I still get the same error message. I don't get it, because I've set the path to the gecko driver.